# Build script not running

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a build script, but am having a problem. My function move() springs an error after I destroy the cloned model when parented into workspace, because it can't set CFrame pos.. Any way to stop this from happening? Error: Model:SetPrimaryCFrame() failed because no PrimaryPart has been set, or the PrimaryPart no longer exists. Please set Model.PrimaryPart before using this.

```lua
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local model = game.ReplicatedStorage.WoodCrate:Clone()
local gridSize = 2
local cratebutton = script.Parent:WaitForChild("brick").TextButton
local allowed = false
local x 
local y
local z
local canPlace = false
local isPlace = false
local canStart = true
local function grid()
    x = math.floor(mouse.Hit.X / gridSize + 0.5) * gridSize
    y = 2
    z = math.floor(mouse.Hit.Z / gridSize + 0.5) * gridSize
end


function move()
    mouse.TargetFilter = model
    grid()
    model:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(CFrame.new(x,y,z))
    end
    
function placingObject()
    if canPlace and isPlace then
    local modelClone = model:Clone()
        modelClone.Parent = workspace.objFolder
             canStart = true
            isPlace = false
        canPlace = false
        
        model:Destroy()
            end
        end

function ChoosingPlacement()   
    if canStart then
        model.Parent = workspace
        mouse.Move:Connect(move)
            canStart = false
            canPlace = true
            isPlace = true
    end
end

cratebutton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(ChoosingPlacement)
mouse.Button1Down:Connect(placingObject)
```

Comment: If you inspect the WoodCrate in ReplicatedStorage, does it have anything set as the PrimaryPart?

Comment: Yeah, it does. It's just I think where I put model:Destroy() where it's causing the error, but not sure how to avoid it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to call a method on an instance that is destroyed and no longer exists. Try this code, and if it works, make sure to mark me as solution!:

```lua
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local model = game.ReplicatedStorage.WoodCrate:Clone()
local gridSize = 2
local cratebutton = script.Parent:WaitForChild("brick").TextButton
local allowed = false
local x 
local y
local z
local canPlace = false
local isPlace = false
local canStart = true
local function grid()
    x = math.floor(mouse.Hit.X / gridSize + 0.5) * gridSize
    y = 2
    z = math.floor(mouse.Hit.Z / gridSize + 0.5) * gridSize
end


function move()
    if model ~= nil then -- this makes sure your model actually exists before trying to modify it!
       mouse.TargetFilter = model
       grid()
       model:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(CFrame.new(x,y,z))
    end
end
    
function placingObject()
    if canPlace and isPlace then
        local modelClone = model:Clone()
        modelClone.Parent = workspace.objFolder
        canStart = true
        isPlace = false
        canPlace = false
        
        model:Destroy()
   end
end
```